# Error in paper clip plugin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ubuntu-10.04

```
  Image Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError
```

I am getting this error.
Installed Image magick, rmagic both specified path in developement.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

Using Snow Leapord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this line  worked for me.

```
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

check logs to see which command failed. probably it looks for other complementary executables not present in your custom path. for example paperclip also needs 'identify' command, provided with imagemagick. so be sure to have all executables you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the Paperclip.options[:command_path] in a file in config/intializers

Comment: can u please specify which file

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have RMagick installed